# CSS columns (NOT grid) not working as intended in Chrome

Tags: html, css, sass, pug

I'm stuck and cannot seem to figure this out.

I am using a class I'm calling "text-col-" followed by a number up to 6 that utilizes the `columns: [number];` CSS. It is working exactly as I intend it to do in Firefox, but not in Chrome. I had the exact opposite problem yesterday, but I guess I didn't fully solve it (clearly). I'm gonna write the specific code under here (so you don't have to look it up), but also link to a live version where you can visually see my problem (in Chrome, that is).

```css
/* SCSS
@for $i from 1 through 6 {
  .text-col-#{$i} {
    width: 100%;
    columns: $i;
    
    @include clearfix;
    @include mq(tablet) {
      @if $i >= 5 {
        clear: both;
        columns: 2;
      }
    }
    @include mq(phone) {
      @if $i >= 3 {
        columns: 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
See the generated css below */

/* CSS */

.text-col-1 {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-columns: 1;
  columns: 1; }
  .text-col-1::after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
    content: " "; }

.text-col-2 {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  columns: 2; }
  .text-col-2::after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
    content: " "; }

.text-col-3 {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-columns: 3;
  columns: 3; }
  .text-col-3::after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
    content: " "; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .text-col-3 {
      -webkit-columns: 1;
      columns: 1; } }

.text-col-4 {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-columns: 4;
  columns: 4; }
  .text-col-4::after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
    content: " "; }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .text-col-4 {
      -webkit-columns: 1;
      columns: 1; } }

.text-col-5 {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-columns: 5;
  columns: 5; }
  .text-col-5::after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
    content: " "; }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .text-col-5 {
      clear: both;
      -webkit-columns: 2;
      columns: 2; } }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .text-col-5 {
      -webkit-columns: 1;
      columns: 1; } }

.text-col-6 {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-columns: 6;
  columns: 6; }
  .text-col-6::after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
    content: " "; }
  @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .text-col-6 {
      clear: both;
      -webkit-columns: 2;
      columns: 2; } }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .text-col-6 {
      -webkit-columns: 1;
      columns: 1; } }
      
 /* CSS to center the text */
 
 [class*="text-col-"] {
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<!-- Written in pug-html (Jade), but here's the generated HTML -->

<div class="container">
  <p class="text-col-1">Text Columns</p>
  <p class="text-col-1">.text-col-1</p>
  <p class="text-col-2">.text-col-2<br/>.text-col-2</p>
  <p class="text-col-3">.text-col-3<br/>.text-col-3<br/>.text-col-3</p>
  <p class="text-col-4">.text-col-4<br/>.text-col-4<br/>.text-col-4<br/>.text-col-4</p>
  <p class="text-col-5">.text-col-5<br/>.text-col-5<br/>.text-col-5<br/>.text-col-5<br/>.text-col-5</p>
  <p class="text-col-6">.text-col-6<br/>.text-col-6<br/>.text-col-6<br/>.text-col-6<br/>.text-col-6<br/>.text-col-6</p>
  <!-- Wrapped-->
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-col-1">Text Columns</div>
  <div class="text-col-1">.text-col-1</div>
  <div class="text-col-2">.text-col-2<br>.text-col-2</div>
  <div class="text-col-3">.text-col-3<br/>.text-col-3<br/>.text-col-3</div>
  <div class="text-col-4">.text-col-4<br/>.text-col-4<br/>.text-col-4<br/>.text-col-4</div>
  <div class="text-col-5">.text-col-5<br/>.text-col-5<br/>.text-col-5<br/>.text-col-5<br/>.text-col-5</div>
  <div class="text-col-6">.text-col-6<br/>.text-col-6<br/>.text-col-6<br/>.text-col-6<br/>.text-col-6<br/>.text-col-6</div>
</div>
```

And here is a link to a "live" version of it: https://fexell.github.io/Lib/test/classes.html#text-cols

So, why is this not working in Chrome?

Images of the problem:
[Firefox shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ETcE.png)
[Chrome shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEQkv.png)

Comment: What's specifically isn't working as intended? We can view the live demo, which is helpful, but need to know exactly what isn't working as intended.

Comment: I've added screenshots at the end of the question that shows what happens in Chrome, as well as what it looks like in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seemingly has to do something with the breaks and how `<br>` gets interpreted in columns.
[watch this](https://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns/breaks.html)

Comment: Thank you. This clarified a lot to me. Just cannot grasp why they would make it behave like that in -webkit-. I "kind of" got it working thanks to your link, but it only works when there's an overflow of text. I guess that's better than nothing. Thanks a ton (gonna mark your answer as the solution).

Comment: jeah i think so too.

Comment: i actually dont know the language, but maybe its possible to to change the column class to a row class and center its content? than add child elements with the needed witdth in %. so the child elements in row 1 have a 100% width of the row. childs in row 2 50% and so on.

Comment: I've tried that using "column-width", but it unfortunately does not take % as a value. I also have a class for percentage container which do what you're implying, which would work just as well. I might as well keep it as an optional class and use it as it is intended so it doesn't look weird in Chrome.
Thanks again :)